# create contact and invoice/lines in one transaction with xml-rpc

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to create a new contact `( res_partner )` and a invoice/lines for this partner in one call to the `xml-rpc api`. I need this to be 1 transaction.

I want to leave the creation of these 3 objects to the `database` and the database should handle the rollback when things go wrong.

I thought it would be possible because there is a relation between the 3 objects.

`res_partner` has many invoices has many `invoice_lines`.

But i have not yet seen an example of such one  write of these 3 objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XMLRPC API gives you interface to the OpenERP objects, not directly to the database. That means that you can use the methods exposed by these objects.

For instance, the *account_move_line.create()* method allows you to create the move and the move lines with a single call to this method. But I'm not aware of a method the allows you to create the partner in the same time.

Any way, even inside these functions the creation of the different records is done in separate transactions I think.

You still have the option to extend the *account_invoice* object by creating a submodule of the *account* module and add the needed one-pass creation functionality...

Let say that you create a new method in the account_invoice class to do your job in the way you want.

```
def create_them_all(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    return "Not yet implemented."
```

You should be able to access it with XMLRPC client, for instance with erppeek:

```
admin >>> model('account.invoice').create_them_all()
'Not yet implemented.'
```

Comment: I want to use erppeek , can i still use the methods than?

Comment: Sure. erppeek allows you to execute public methods of the OpenERP objects. I'll give an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Each XML-RPC call is its own transaction
- Server side, each OpenERP action is its own transaction, no matter how many calls it takes

If you want several calls to be treated as one you would need to do as @AndrieBoyanov suggested and create a method on the server side that does all the things at once, and then you can call that via XML-RPC.